# htaccess maintenance page with a url variable exception

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I searched for a while, but couldn't find the exact answer. So here it goes.

I have a membership site that has a PayPal IPN listener. This needs to be active and accesable at all times!

I am doing a maintenance update today that might take a few hours. How do I add an execption for a URL like this in my .htaccess page:

```
http://mycoolwebsite.com/?listener=IPN
```

Here is my .htaccess page so far:

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# ip address so i can access
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=xx.xx.xx.xx

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$
```

Thanks NINJAS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# skip /?listener=IPN from rewrites
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^listener=IPN$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rest of your rules follow
```

**PS:** I notice that you just have 3 `RewriteCond` lines without any `RewriteRule` line. Which is not really doing anything for you.

Comment: oh, really ? I didn't even see that. So I can just take out the RewriteCond if front of those to correct it?

Comment: Yes I guess you can, I am unsure what those lines are doing.

Comment: ha! so I can just do this
`%{REMOTE_ADDR} !=xx.xx.xx.xx
%{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/.*$
%{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$`